# programmatically add a button column

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, webforms

I am trying to add a `ButtonField` to a `GridView` programmatically.

So in aspx it looks like this:

```
<asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Image" 
                 CommandName="buttonClicked" 
                 ImageUrl="~/checkdailyinventory.bmp" />
```

This is what I have tried in C# to replicate.

```
 GridView genGridView = new GridView();

        //Where the xml gets bonded to the data grind
        XmlDataSource xds = new XmlDataSource();
        xds.Data = xml;
        xds.DataBind();
        xds.EnableCaching = false;


        genGridView.DataSource = xds;
        genGridView.DataBind();


        // formating is done here

        ButtonField test3 = new ButtonField();
        test3.ButtonType = ButtonType.Image;
        test3.CommandName = "buttonClicked";
        test3.ImageUrl = "~/checkdailyinventory.bmp";
        genGridView.Columns.Add(test3);
```

This does not create any new columns
Any help would be apperciated.

## UPDATE Progress

I was able to create the columns, but they are the first column, not the last.  To do this I had to put the button creation and add the column before the data binding.

```
GridView genGridView = new GridView();

        //Where the xml gets bonded to the data grind
        XmlDataSource xds = new XmlDataSource();
        xds.Data = xml;
        xds.DataBind();
        xds.EnableCaching = false;

        //Set the rowdatabound before binding.  This will allow the correct function to be called.
        genGridView.RowDataBound += new GridViewRowEventHandler(inventoryGridView_RowDataBound);
        genGridView.RowCommand += new GridViewCommandEventHandler(inventoryGridView_RowCommand);

        ButtonField test3 = new ButtonField();
        test3.ButtonType = ButtonType.Image;
        test3.CommandName = "buttonClicked";
        test3.ImageUrl = "checkdailyinventory.bmp";

        genGridView.Columns.Add(test3);
        genGridView.DataSource = xds;
        genGridView.DataBind();
```

Also the button fails to actually do anything even though I have all the variables set correctly, but one step at a time I guess.

Minor Edit:

I think I figure out why the buttons aren't working.  In the html it should look like this:

```
<td><input type="image" src="checkdailyinventory.bmp" onclick="javascript:__doPostBack('inventoryGridView','buttonClicked$2')" style="border-width:0px;" /></..>
```

while it actually looks like this:

```
<td><input type="image" src="checkdailyinventory.bmp" onclick="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl03','buttonClicked$2')" style="border-width:0px;" /></..>
```

So I need to figure out how to replace `ct103` with `inventoryGridView`

Comment: why dont you use DataGridView component?

Comment: I am relatively new to asp.net and c# so I haven't really been able to get it to work properly.

Comment: Where is the code above being run? Page_Load?

Comment: The code is being run on page_load. Although it has to go through a few functions to get to where it finally creates the table.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're creating genGridView in the code behind but not adding it to your page.

I gather the GridView is defined in the markup.  If so, try removing the line

```
GridView genGridView = new GridView();
```

and you should be able to add your column to the object on the page.

Hint:  You will probably need to add the item in OnInit (or a method called from OnInit) as well.

Comment: The gridview gets created programmatically. So I am generating a bunch of GridViews and then putting them all into their own cell.  Then I put them into a row and then add the row to the asp:table I have defined

Comment: So the gridviews are getting to the page but the butttons are not, or are you not getting even the gridviews? Also, do you have a ContentPlaceHolder in the table on the page that you are adding to?

Comment: The gridviews are getting into the page, but the buttons are not.  And I do not have a ContentPlaceHolder since I am using an asp:table to display all the gridviews.

`div id="div2" style="height: 500px; width: 300px; overflow: scroll;" onscroll="OnScroll2(this)">
                                <asp:Table ID="Table2" runat="server">
                                </asp:Table>
                            </div>
                        </td>`